# How can I change window.rootViewController in Xcode 12's new SwiftUI App lifecycle?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am new to SwiftUI. I have a new project, `Test`, running the SwiftUI interface and the SwiftUI App lifecycle. This lifecycle is new to iOS 14 and Xcode 12.

I'd like to use a Github package, [BetterSheet](https://github.com/egeniq/BetterSheet), in my project. I've added the package dependency. However, as described in the [Basic Usage section of the readme](https://github.com/egeniq/BetterSheet#basic-usage), I have to initialize `UIHostingController` with sheet support in `SceneDelegate.swift`, like so:

```swift
window.rootViewController = UIHostingController.withBetterSheetSupport(rootView: ContentView())
```

My app does not have `SceneDelegate.swift` due to the nature of the new lifecycle. I have `TestApp.swift` instead:

```swift
@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

I want to use the BetterSheet package in my project, but this first step seems to get in the way. How can I get around this?

Comment: Create a new project that uses SceneDelegate.

Comment: In response to your comment, that seems to be the best course of action from here. The new SwiftUI lifecycle is too new and the documentation is lacking at this point.

Comment: I wouldn't say documentation is lacking, it's more that developers insist on wanting to use UIKit paradigms for SwiftUI apps, whereas Apple is clearly trying to do the opposite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suspect you can do something like this, [based on their UIHostingController+BetterSheet.swift](https://github.com/egeniq/BetterSheet/blob/master/Sources/BetterSheet/UIHostingController%2BBetterSheet.swift#L15) code.

```
@main
struct TestApp: App {
    let coordinator = BetterSheetCoordinator()
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            BetterSheetSupport(coordinator: coordinator) {
                ContentView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I would question the value of this library. Sheet presentation in iOS 14 with the standard library works just fine, and the library itself haven't been updated for 14 months.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm trying my best to implement this now, however I'm getting some issues with finding `BetterSheetCoordinator` and `BetterSheetSupport` in scope, even after restarting Xcode and importing `BetterSheet` (I'll mark as accepted answer once I get it working).

The reason why I want to use this package is because SwiftUI's `Sheet` view can be moved/dismissed with a swipe gesture, and I am trying to have a Sheet view that cannot be moved.

Comment: You're probably looking for [fullScreenCover()](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-present-a-full-screen-modal-view-using-fullscreencover)

Comment: And the types in question might be internal to the library, so you probably can't do this without importing the code direction into your project.

Comment: I will use fullScreenCover(). And you're correct, the types are internal to the library.

Comment: `BetterSheet` attaches a `UIViewControllerRepresentable` struct to enable drag-down to dismiss callbacks which's not possible with SwiftUI sheet(s)